# Is using an old book's solution considered cheating?

Tags: cheating

I'm currently solving a coding problem. I remembered that i came across this problem in another book i studied myself to improve my coding in the summer.  That book has the same problem to this assignment. I understand the answer and know how to explain it but not sure if it is cheating to use that piece of code for my assignment.

Comment: Welcome to academia.sx! As it is, we cannot answer your question: the answer would solely depend on what rules your prof set for your course. I will thus vote to close the question.

Comment: @cbeleitessupportsMonica While i'm well aware that it is very specific to the professor's rules, i asked the question to get a broader understanding of what others might do in this scenario so i can learn from others experience. I apologize if the question is worded in a very specific way but just wanted to get others thought on the matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only your professor can answer such a question, though your syllabus may give guidance. "Found" solutions may be permitted or forbidden. My rules and my colleague's will probably be quite different.

But you will learn more if you "forget" you saw it (i.e. don't consult it) and try to write the solution on your own. Your course is about learning, not about producing solutions efficiently.

But you would be wise to tell your prof that you saw the solution earlier and that you worked without referencing it.

And, of course, it may not be possible to completely forget.

Comment: +1, but I've been in courses where finding solutions efficiently was part of the stated learning goals.

Comment: Yes, in such a  case @cbeleitessupportsMonica, then the rules are clear. But they aren't universal. I'm assuming we have the same definition of "finding". That is, research is encouraged.

Comment: Well with the code i understand the fundamental concept of it and how it is applied. If asked, i can easily explain the code in detail and rewrite it and even apply it to other problems. However, as you stated earlier, it is hard to forget something if you learned it before. He did not state anything regarding cheating or researching answers in his syllabus. @Buffy

Answer (score 6):

One more thought in addition to Buffy's answer:

Transparency is maybe the solution here: tell your prof "I remember this problem, I met it studying *book* last summer. How shall I proceed with the assignment?"

- This will ensure that there won't be any ground for accusing you of cheating
- Prof may give you another assignment, from which you can learn more.

Comment: I "met" the problem! Love it.

Answer (score -3):

No, it's not cheating. You were tasked with solving a problem, therefore your task is to solve.

Unless you were meant to create a new method or something specific you are merely solving the problem which is to find a way to solve a problem.

Using an old answer is like calling a redundant function. And as long as you get to understand how that code works in your answer then all is fine.